# Needing wifi signal restrengthened on piggy-backed router system

Tags: wireless-networking, router

My question involves WiFi run from a piggybacked or double router system arranged for a home network.

My roomie, the system host, has asked about the process required for resetting the dchp/dhcp in order to bring it back to a single IP id, thus narrowing and sharpening our available signal strength, rather than trying to deal with the multiple ones generated from constant resetting of both the secondary and base.

I realize there are at least 3 different approaches to the problem, though I believe that perhaps simply disabling it on the second router linked to the base may well provide the simplest solution.

Comment: What are the makes and models of routers involved? How are they connected?

Answer (score 0):

Only one router should be broadcasting WiFi, because if two or more routers are routing, you will have [double-NAT](http://www.practicallynetworked.com/networking/fixing_double_nat.htm), which severely messes with your internet connections.

The signal strength has nothing to do with how many IP addresses are provided by the routers. Only one router should be providing DHCP; all other routers, if you have multiple wired Ethernet connections which require multiple routers to extend the wired LAN, then set all the rest to ['bridged' mode](https://reporting.samknows.com/bridging.html) so all the rest do is distribute the LAN by switching.

The router with the most powerful CPU should be used as the master router. Put that in one corner of the house, and then put an [aluminum foil reflector](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_7156948_make-wi_fi-antenna-booster.html), attached with double-sided cellophane tape to cardboard from a cereal box, so the signal is [concentrated in a beam](https://wifiantenna.wordpress.com/parabolicwifi-antenna/) to the rest of the house.

If you are unable to get good coverage to all the house, then add a [WiFi repeater](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Awifi%20repeater).